# Mi Base de Datos no lee mis registros y no sé por qué-

Tags: mysql

La conexión a la base de datos se realiza sin problemas mi problema es que cuando pongo los datos en los input y envío, no me aparece ningún error, pero a la base de datos no llega nada:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Market</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Registro</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="registro.php">
        <input type="text" name="usuario">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

registro.php

```
<?php

    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registro');

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registro(usuario, password) VALUES('$usuario', '$password')";

    mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta algo asi:

```
if (mysqli_query($consulta, $sql)){
echo "successfully created";
```

Donde $sql es tu 'insert into ****'
Ya sabes.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que te recomiendo es validar que los campos no lleguen vacíos, dicho esto, yo añadiría un `if` donde se valide que la conexión se ejecuta correctamente, así:

```
if($conexion === FALSE){
    die(print_r(mysqli_error(), TRUE));
    }
```

Luego cuando ya tienes el query en la variable `$sql` es necesario que lo ejecutes, luego de ejecutarlo validamos si hay errores con un `if` y si no hay pues mostramos un `alert` (eso es opcional) y finalmente redireccionamos al formulario de origen, así:

```
$rs = $conexion->query($sql);
    
if($rs === FALSE){
  die(print_r(mysqli_error(), TRUE));
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Usuario registrado'); location.href='url_formulario.php';</script>";
}
```

Finalmente todo junto quedaría asi:

```
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registro');

if($conexion === FALSE){
die(print_r(mysqli_error(), TRUE));
}

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "iNSERT INTO registro(usuario, password) VALUES('$usuario', '$password')";

$rs = $conexion->query($sql);

if($rs === FALSE){
  die(print_r(mysqli_error(), TRUE));
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Usuario registrado'); location.href='url_formulario.php';</script>";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Recuerda modificar `url_formulario.php` por la URL real de tu formulario. Ojala sea lo que buscas. Saludos.